# Regressing each column i of dataframe 1 on each column i of dataframe 2 using for loop and store coefficient estimates

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, linear-regression

I have two data frames each with n observations and m variables. Each observation represents a country and each variable represents time=t when the observation was made. The first data frame includes observations of y, while the second data frame includes observations of x.

```
#Creating data frame 1
countries <- c('Country 1', 'Country 2', 'Country 3', 'Country 4'
time <- as.date(c('19/04/2020', '20/04/2020', '21/04/2020', '22/04/2020', '23/04/2020', '24/04/2020'))
y <- c('1000', '4000', '3203', '3256', '3583', '3214')
df1 <- data.frame(countries, time, y)
df1

#Creating data frame 2
countries <- c('Country 1', 'Country 2', 'Country 3', 'Country 4'
time <- as.date(c('19/04/2020', '20/04/2020', '21/04/2020', '22/04/2020', '23/04/2020', '24/04/2020'))
x <- c('294817', '298550', '298550', '225280', '538550', '232550')
df2 <- data.frame(countries, time, x)
df2
```

My ultimate goal is to estimate multiple linear models while always regressing the column i of data frame 1 on column i of data frame 2. For example starting with column 1 of df1 regressed on column 1 of df2, then continuing with column 2 of df1 regressed on column 2 of df2. The coefficient estimates shall be stored in a new data frame for each regression. I would like to do this with a for loop as I want to apply different models beside the linear model.
Thank you for any help.

Comment: Hi Dom1994. Welcome to Stackoverflow. Is there a reason, why the observations of x and y aren't stored in the same data.frame? You can use `model <- lm(unlist(df1[,3]) ~ unlist(df2[,3]))` and access your coefficients by `model$coefficients`. Further more you can loop over the index 3, i.e. replacing 3 with your counting variable.

Comment: Something is missing from your lines `countries <- c('Country 1', 'Country 2', 'Country 3', 'Country 4'`